# DIV width not listening to my CSS

Tags: css, html, width

The code below is an example of what I am trying to do, I need this div to span 600px wide however regardless if I put max-width: 600px; or width: 600px; it is still the width of my PC screen.

How can I make it 600px wide?

```
<style>
.errormsg3 { 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color:red;
    padding:8px;
    max-width: 600px;
}
</style>

<?PHP
if (isset($_SESSION['sess_msg'])) {
    echo '<div class="errormsg3">' .$_SESSION['sess_msg']. '</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['sess_msg']);
} 
?>
```

**UPDATE**

It is working now, firefox seems to be caching my site so  maybe thats why it wouldn't work before.

The div is red, is it possible to add padding to the div, outside of the red part, so there is like a padding/space that is white

Comment: Use width, not max-width (IE issues), but this really should work. Something else must be going on with your CSS.

Comment: Weird thing is just started working, its like firefox keeps caching things on my site I think, all day I have had weird issue where I update something and firefox doesnt show it correctly.  I need to align this div center somehow though?

Comment: All - from his post: "regardless if I put max-width: 600px; or width: 600px"

Comment: ah - the lovely cache issue.  Make sure you have caching turned completely off for development, and that you actually refresh the entire page (or it won't reload css files)

Comment: that must be what happend thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CSS works fine for me. Are you sure you don't have another CSS rule that's overriding it? Try using a tool like Firebug that can show you the computed style for an element and where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

I would try debugging it with Firebug to ensure that nothing is overriding that div class, and checking to see how the containing elements are laid out.

Answer (score 0):

```
-max-width: 600px;
+width: 600px;
```

IE doesn't like max-width. Tested and works in IE/FF/Chrome.

Comment: To clarify -- IE 6 and below didn't honour max-width; later versions need a width as well (such as a percentage) which max-width will cap.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is nothing inside of your  that is larger than the div.  IE sometimes (depends on version) renders divs with larger interior content by expanding the div to account for the content.

The easy way to test this is to add overflow:hidden and see if it hides anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a HTML file

```
<html><head><style>
body {text-align: center;}
.errormsg3 { 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color:red;
    padding:8px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<body>
if (isset($_SESSION['sess_msg'])) {
    echo '<div class="errormsg3">' .$_SESSION['sess_msg']. '</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['sess_msg']);
} 
</body>
```

I get a centred 600px wide message on FF 3.5.2, Opera 9.64, IE 8.0.6001.18813 on Vista 32 bit.  IE needs the extra text-align to centre the block, the `margin: 0 auto` does for the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Often adding important behind the attribute will help, because it will override all the other widths the parents declared. You need to write it like this:

```
width: 600px !important;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add overflow: auto; to your CSS.